# Recursively rename all files in directory by using relative path separated by underscores

Tags: bash, unix, rename, batch-rename

I have a directory structure like below where the structure is known, and the file names 
repeat themselves. I want to rename the files so they are unique, so that

`a/0/widgets/AL/part-1.gz` becomes

`a/0/widgets/AL/a_0_widgets_AL_part-1.gz`,

and

`b/0/widgets/AL/part-1.gz` becomes

`b/0/widgets/AL/b_0_widgets_AL_part-1.gz`, etc.

This way I can copy all of the files into one top level directory while keeping all known information about the file and not clobbering any files because of file name repeats.

Suggestions?

```
├── a
│   ├── 0
│   │   └── widgets
│   │       ├── AL
│   │       │   ├── part-1.gz
│   │       │   └── part-2.gz
│   │       ├── AK
│   │       │   ├── part-3.gz
│   │       │   └── part-4.gz
| ....

├── b
│   ├── 0
│   │   └── widgets
│   │       ├── AL
│   │       │   ├── part-1.gz
│   │       │   └── part-2.gz
│   │       ├── AK
│   │       │   ├── part-3.gz
│   │       │   └── part-4.gz
| ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this hacky solution. Easier to do in Python than Bash IMHO.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                               

import os                                                           

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/mnt/orig_data'):            
    if len(files) > 0:                                              
        for file in files:                                          
            parts = root.split('/')                                 
            new_file = '%s_%s' % ('_'.join(parts[-4:]), file, )     
            os.rename('/'.join([root, file]),                       
                  '/'.join([root, new_file]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -print | while read path; do
  dir="$(dirname "$path")"
  prefix="${dir:2}"
  prefix="${prefix//\//_}"
  mv "$path" "$dir/${prefix}_$(basename "$path")"
done
```